# As codificações não funcionam num ficheiro com OpenCV em Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, codificação-de-caracteres, opencv, unicode

Eu segui o tutorial de detecção de faces, utilizando OpenCV e escrevi em Python 3. Neste ficheiro, não se utiliza `print`. Eu já sei que Python 3 é internacional, é compatível com UTF-8 e não precisa de codificações. Mas mesmo assim, não apareceu um acento numa imagem. Observe que o ficheiro é salvo em UTF-8.

Coloquei assim:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
# -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-
import os
import sys

# import the necessary packages
import argparse
import cv2
```

Coloquei três codificações para funcionar em três diferentes sistemas operativos.

Eu mudei de inglês para português, escrevendo uma frase "É um gato":

```
# loop over the cat faces and draw a rectangle surrounding each
for (i, (x, y, w, h)) in enumerate(rects):
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (140, 175, 84), 2)
    cv2.putText(image, "É um gato  # {}".format(i + 1), (x, y - 10),
             cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.55, (0, 0, 255), 2)  #5faf54
```

Executei no terminal integrado do Visual Studio Code no Ubuntu 16.04. Não adianta sugerir que execute no terminal nativo porque também aconteceu a mesma coisa.

Também tentei:

```
cv2.encode('utf-8')
```

E não funcionou.

Apareceu "?? um gato #1" numa imagem ao executar e compilar:

[image: Exemplo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até onde eu saiba, não há implementação na função PutText para suporte a unicode e caracteres especiais, portanto, o problema não é com o python.

Um recurso muito utilizado, no entanto,para esta e outros prints de caracteres especiais é a função draw.text do [Pillow (PIL)](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.text).

Que utiliza, de padrão  [uma fonte unicode](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html?highlight=unicode#PIL.ImageFont.truetype).

PS: A função encode do OpenCV (agora imencode), se refere somente ao encoding da imagem em si. Documentação: [Aqui](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=encode#imencode)